# Get user meta (cocoaLibSpotify)

Tags: ios, objective-c, spotify, meta, cocoalibspotify-2.0

I need to get hold of a user's profile image. Can't seem to find anything that points me in the right direction. And also, how can I get the full name of the user (not the username)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the full name is available, it'll be in the `displayName` property of the user. User images are not provided by CocoaLibSpotify.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But what determines if the full name is available? (It appeared once, very randomly which makes it quite strange.)